# php - alternative for document.getElementById

Tags: php

hi guys i just want to know if there is an alternative syntax for onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" on php. Beceause its not working even it is inside the echo.tnx
[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8BYq.png)

Comment: Put your code in the question, don't link a screenshot of code.

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a construct used in **JavaScript** not PHP!

Comment: Regarding the problem: you need to escape your single quotes in the document.getElementById call.

Comment: i try to remove the single quote but i cant click it

Comment: Of course you cannot click it — now you have specified a variable to `document.getElementById` named `id01`.

Comment: See, `document.getElementById(id01)` is **very** different than `document.getElementById('id01')`. One is a variable the other a fixed string constant.

Comment: sorry im just a beginner. by the way is there anyway i can do for me to click it?

Comment: why you write in php, just write in html tag

Comment: because i want one button per image.

Answer (score 0):

First up: `document.getElementById` is a construct used in JavaScript and has nothing to do with PHP.

The problem you are running into is that you are not escaping the single quotes in your string:

```
echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById(' <- there is your problem
```

PHP thinks that the string ends here since you told it so with `'`.

But the string is in fact not at its end so you need to escape the single quote in order to make it work:

```
echo '<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'id0\')...';
```

This goes for all single quotes in your string of course.

Comment: i try but i cant click the button